# Probably misdiagnosed "Command textiota unavailable in encoding T1" error

Tags: babel, font-encodings, characters

I'm writing which is overall in English but with a few quotes with Greek characters in-between.
Now I'm getting a strange error saying ""Command textiota unavailable in encoding T1" (if you follow the indicated line, see snapshot below) which seems to be caused by a new Greek quote.
Before asking this question, I tried extracting a minimal version producing the error (see below) and the minimal version fails to reproduce the error, despite the two quotes being the same !
So it seems the real problem comes from elesewhere.

Here is the minimal example (that unfortunately fails to reproduce the error) :

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{book}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1cm,nohead,foot=0.5cm]{geometry}
\pagestyle{plain}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[greek, english]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{microtype}


\begin{document}
\footnotesize

This text is in English. And here is some Greek : \foreignlanguage{greek}{μυστικὰ θεὰματα}

\end{document}
```

And here is a snapshot of the error message :

[image]

Comment: If the example doesn't reproduce the error then it would be best to find another example that does reproduce it. Start adding elements from your original document to the example until the error appears, then try to remove potentially irrelevant elements until the example is minimal again.

Comment: Check if the `I`  from `It` is really an I and not a Iota. They look alike but are not the same chars.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get the error also with the following document:

The problem is that the first I is not an I but a Iota (U+0399).

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[greek, english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}
Ι I 
\end{document}
```

The error message shows you exactly where the problem is. Look how the line break is at the wrong I:

```
! LaTeX Error: Command \textIota unavailable in encoding T1.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.13 Ι       %<---------------- that is the problem
        I
```

Comment: You guessed it all correctly, thanks